# SharePoint Online List - Can Calendar View Show Images?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calendar, json-formatting

This list has a *Flag* column which is of **Image** column type. 
I created a "Flag only" calendar view to display only this image column.

However on load, the views show the image filename instead of image.
Is there anyway to show the actual image?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is **not possible** currently in [modern Calendar view in SharePoint Online/Microsoft Lists](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/create-a-modern-calendar-view-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/).

You cannot show [image column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/06/all-you-need-to-know-about-new-image-column-type-in-sharepoint-online/) in modern calendar monthly/weekly view.

JSON formatting capabilities are also very limited for calendar views. You can only add additional classes to events using `additionalEventClass`.

**Related Read**:

1. [Calendar view customizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-calendar-formatting)
2. [Create a modern Calendar view in SharePoint Online/Microsoft Lists](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/create-a-modern-calendar-view-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/)

Comment: Thanks @ganesh. Yes that's what I can find out too. I was thinking if there are any other ways around it

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to achieve this using SharePoint out of the box capabilities of calendar view.